# VBA using drop down lists on other worksheets to hide rows automatically

Tags: vba, excel

Afternoon all!

I am using the results of various drop down lists to hide the relevant rows on a spreadsheet as the value on the drop down list is changed (so automatically).

With some googling, I have come across the below set up which works nicely, although I have now hit a snag when trying to specify drop down list cell from another worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim disabled As Boolean
    If Range("D2") = "Yes" Then
        disabled = True
    End If

    If disabled Then
        Rows("3:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else        
        Rows("3:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End sub
```

Using the following has not worked, and googling for a solution has lead me up many a dead end:

```
If Sheets("Topsheet").Range("D27") = "Yes" Then
```

Am I unable to use values from a neighbouring sheet when declaring a variable due to it being a private sub?

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stumped on this for a couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be massively simplified. Try using this (You'll have to update the sheet name if it's not the same as yours)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("SheetWithRowsToBeHidden").Rows("3:8").EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(Me.Range("D27").Value2 = "Yes", True, False)
End Sub
```

Also, where have you put this code? Have you put it inside a Module or is it in the Sheet Object? It needs to be in the Sheet Object that has the dropdowns on.

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for the code, I agree that is much easier! The code is contained within the sheet object ("Build Detail"), but the problem lies with the drop down being on a separate worksheet - is there a way around this? To work around this, I have tried to link the output of the dropdown (on "Topsheet") to a cell on "Build Detail" but while this changes the value in 'Build Details'!E6, the rows do not become hidden until 'Build Details'!E6 is double clicked and enter is hit - hence becoming rather manual.